# vbs check if bat running

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I have a batch file that running in computer and check something - **Start.bat**

I want to write VBS that check in the background if the batch file is running or not. if run, do nothing. if not, run.

This code always return me that batch file is running, but he didnt.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Do
    Set locator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
    Set service = locator.ConnectServer()
    Set props = service.ExecQuery _
       ("select name, description from Win32_Process where name = 'Start.bat'")
    num = props.Count


    If num > 0 Then
      WScript.Echo "Program is running"
    Else
       WScript.Echo "Program is not running" 
    End If


    Set WSHShell = Nothing
    Wscript.Sleep 1000
loop
```

Comment: Change the name of your batch file, `Start` is a command!

Comment: @Compo still not working..

Comment: Maxim, it wasn't an answer to your question, it was general advice, by way of comment.

Comment: You would need to rather give the batch file a title and search by title as batch files are sequence files that launches `cmd.exe` to execute a batch of commands.

Comment: how can i search by title in vbs?

Comment: Maybe just call the tasklist command? Usimg WScript.Run and calling `tasklist /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq titlename"` where title name is the name of whatever you start the batch as. I.e. in the batch after echo off add `title titlename` which will launch the batch with that title.

Comment: Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
do
oShell.Run "tasklist /fi maxim eq cmd.exe", , True
loop

Comment: its not working

Comment: Do not search for **volatile** `cmd` title. Query `"select name, CommandLine, description from Win32_Process where name = 'cmd.exe'"` and check `CommandLine`.

Comment: Also, please [edit] your question when you need to provide additional information or have modified your code. Do not bury relevant information in comments.